# How do I add jquery plugins to jsfiddle.net?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsfiddle

for example, I want to add this to jsfiddle.net

[jQuery Validation](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

is this possible?

Comment: I am pretty sure (60% might be) :P your answer will get closed: do you mean add `<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>` in first row, first column ? cheers `:)`

Comment: Use the `Add Resources` action on the left panel. Note, this does not always work with some sites if you're trying to link through to a script hosted somewhere else.

Comment: @Tats_innit what I wanted was how to import the file itself, not include it in my code. :)

Comment: @ReyL ah okies, :) although you don't deserve any down vote I will up vote you anyways ++1,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the URL to a version of that plug-in, you can add it as a resource by clicking on the link "Add resource" on the left-hand side, entering the URL and clicking the big <kbd>+</kbd> button.

Note that unless you are hosting the URL yourself or you are using an acknowledge static location (i.e. on Google CDN), the resource URL might stop working at any time.

Comment: so I can't upload it directly to jsfiddle right?

Comment: I just add the following to the HTML section: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 5):

In the left hand panel, there is a section called "Add Resources". Click this, then add the URL into the field and click the <kbd>+</kbd> button. This will add your resource (JS or CSS) to the page without your having to worry about how to code it correctly.

[image: Add resources panel on jsFiddle]

Answer (score 1):

In the Add Resources tab, fill the URL to the plugin and click the + button.